# Getting field-level security without apex coding in SalesforceMobileSDK

Tags: apex, mobilesdk, ios, feedcomment, salesforcesdk

By declaring the Apex Class with sharing keyword, non-admin user can select or edit field-level security.

How can i able to do this in mobile application only using SalesforceMobileSDK without implement any Apex coding?